# L1 regularization vs maximal entropy?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Solving for ill-posed linear models, I saw that Maximal entropy is also parsimonious and in that regards similar to L1-sparsity promoting regularization. How is it different and are they interchangeable ? is it the entropy maximization always convex?

In the L1 case I use PBDM to minimize the combined terms looking for a sparse solution:

$$ ||Ax-y||_2^2 + \lambda ||x||_1$$

This is convex, and stright forward to solve, even though I'm not sure how to get the $\lambda$ parameters yet.

For maximal entropy, [I read](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/applications/max_entropy.html) that I need to maximize :

$$   \sum_i x_i \log(x_i)  $$

such that $Ax = y, F*x <= g $

so what is F here, and is g similar to $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your problem is only $A x = y$,

$F \circ x \preceq g$ it could make your problem infeasible, I wouldn't artificially add it. If you don't know what $F$ or $g$ to use, you could start with $F=0$, and $g=0$, so that accepts any $x$, in other words don't use that constraint.

About the entropy maximization, you drop a negative sign in your expression, you must maximize $\sum -x \log(x)$

The regularization effect is related to convexity, the derivative of $-x \log(x)$  is $-(1 + \log(x))$. As $x$ increase the derivative increase, so if you have degrees of freedom that let you vary $x_i$ and $x_j$, the entropy maximization will pull those two values closer to each other, i.e. you can increase entropy by increasing the smaller and decreasing the greater of them.

In particular, a well known result is that under the constraint $\sum x=1$, the uniform distribution maximizes entropy.

Summarizing

The L1 regularization will pull values towards zero. Maximum entropy regularization will pull the values closer to each other.

### Edit

How to use it for positive and negative values.

If you want to use this regularization for positive and negative values you could think of some transformation $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$.

If you use $\exp(x)$ as you mentioned in the comment, you end up maximizing $ \sum x \exp(x)$. Negative values will have negligible contributions, while positive values may have huge contributions to the sum, so it will probably move the negative values to as a function of the positive ones.

Also,the minimum is $0 = x \exp(x) + \exp(x) = (x+1) \exp(x)$, what $x=1", has in special.

Maybe it would be preferrable to use $\exp(x^2)$, then the positive and negative side will look the same. The critical points are $(2x \cdot x^2 + 2x)\exp(x^2) =2\, x \,(x^2+1) \exp(x^2) = 0$, i.e. it has a minimum in $x=0$.

The other point is that $\exp(x)$ or $\exp(x^2)$ is prone to overflow. If you want to avoid problems due to the exponential growth of the exponential function you could try $x^2$, but this is not convex any more $x + 2x \log(x^2)=0$, has three solutions $x=0$, $x=\pm e^{-1/4}$.

Then the things starts to get too complicated, and this is not entropy maximization anymore. If you are open to other regularizations I would give L2 regularization a chance.

Comment: thank you for the answer! It seems that using this method I'm restricted to only positive values in x (because of the log(x)), is there a way to circumvent that and use ME for any both negative and positive x values? (take an exp of everything?)

Comment: Exp could be something, however for floating point you could have numeric problems.

Comment: thank you again for the detailed answer!